# Controlling Indicator Lights on DJI Drone

Tags: dji-sdk

Is is possible to manually control the indicator lights using the dji SDK? I haven't found anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJIFlightControllerLEDsSettings.html

Like that?  has front and rear?